# Regex to get text between 2 large spaces

Tags: regex

I want to try and regex this text to only get "Second Baptist School" as the output by using `Customer:` as the set beginning for it to recognize.  How would I get it so that it recognizes the beginning and gets all of the text in between the large sections of blanks?

```
Customer:           Second Baptist School               Date of Sale:       9/26/2022
```

Right now I'm using `Customer:\s*([^ -.]+)` but it only gets "Second" as the output.

Comment: It's scanned text from a pdf so it looks like it's tabs in between

Comment: That works perfectly! Customer:\s*(.*?) {2,} is exactly what I needed. Thank you, I'm very new to regex

Comment: Okay, I've posted that as an answer. I also modified it to use any whitespace character. Use whichever is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for 2 or more white spaces with:

```
Customer:\s*(.*?)\s{2,}
```

this should align with your above examples. The `{2,}` says 2 or more.

https://regex101.com/r/1HapOO/1

Comment: `{2,}` means *two or more*, not "more than 2". `Customer:\s*(.*?)\s{2,}` = `Customer:\s*(.*?)\s{2}`

Comment: Oh, yea, guess I phrased that wrong. Thanks.